# How to play SKAction sound from another class

Tags: swift, skaction

I have a class with a method to play a sound file:

```
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation

class Sound: SKScene {

    func play(fileName:String){

            var sound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed(fileName, waitForCompletion: false)
            runAction(sound)
    }
}
```

When I call this method from another class like so, no sound is played (although including a `println` tells me that the function is executing).

```
var sound = Sound()
sound.play("tick.mp3")
```

Am I unable to play a sound file via another class? Could someone explain why this is? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making your sound class as a subclass of skscene? Why are you doing that?  Your sound is playing in an instance of that scene class.

I'm not sure why you're not playing sounds directly from your main scene.. That would make more sense

If you really need this kind of sound class I suppose you could subclass sknode and add that node to your main scene..

Comment: I thought that using a class like this would allow me to create a variable `var sound = Sound()` and then simply call `sound.play("Sound_file.mp3")`. This would prevent me from creating a play sound function in each scene. I guess not, I'll stick to playing the sounds from my main scene. Thanks for clearing that up for me